Complex function given residue

In $\Omega = \{z\in \Bbb C : (z-2)(z^2-2z+2)\neq 0 \}$ determine the analytic expression of an holomorphic function on $\Omega$ such that

$z = 1-i$ is a removable singularity
$z = 1+i$ is a 1-pole with $\text{Res}_f(1+i) = e^{i\pi/4}$
$z = 2$ is a 2-pole with $\text{Res}_f(2) = 3i$
$\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z) = \pi$



Here's my attempt, since I know that a function with a k-pole in $z_0$ could be written in its Laurent expansion as
$$f(z) = \frac{b_k}{(z-z_0)^k} + \frac{b_{k-1}}{(z-z_0)^{k-1}}+ \dots + \frac{b_1}{(z-z_0)} +\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n}$$
where the highlighted part is a holomorphic function in a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$, I've started with (2),(3) leading me to think that $f$ could be written as
$$\label{eq_1}\tag{1} f(z) = \frac{3i}{(z-2)^2} + \frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{(z-(1+i))} + \tilde f(z) $$
And then I was hoping that the part (1),(4) could be resolved by $\tilde f(z)
$ using
$$\tilde f(z) = \frac{z-(1-i)}{z-(1-i)}\arctan(\text{Re}(z))$$
that I think satisfies the requirement even though I'm a little dubious about the real part that maybe could mess up with holomorphy...
Adding everything together in $(1)$
$$f(z) = \frac{3i}{(z-2)^2} + \frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{(z-(1+i))} + \frac{z-(1-i)}{z-(1-i)}\arctan(\text{Re}(z))$$
Is it a possible resolution? Are there smarter ways to find such functions? Thank you for your help!

Do you believe that $\arctan\bigl(\operatorname{Re}(z)\bigr)$ is an holomorphic function?

$\tilde{f}(z) = \pi + \operatorname{sinc}(z-(1-i))$ does the job.

@Abezhiko Are you claiming that $\lim_{z\to\infty}\operatorname{sinc}(z)=0$?

@JoséCarlosSantos Before you commenting actually I do not spend much time on the holomorphic part but much more on the limit part, so I'm definitely wrong. What can I use?

Take$$f(z)=\frac{az^3+bz^2+cz+d}{(z-2)^2(z^2-2z+2)}+\pi.$$Clearly, $f$ is a holomorphic function defined for each $z\in\Omega$ and $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\pi$.
On the other hand:\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=1-i}f(z)&=\left(-\frac12-\frac i2\right)a-\frac{ib}{2}+\left(\frac14-\frac i4\right)c+\frac d4;\\\operatorname{res}_{z=1+i}f(z)&=\left(-\frac12+\frac i2\right)a+\frac{ib}2+\left(\frac14+\frac i4\right)c+\frac d4;\\\operatorname{res}_{z=2}f(z)&=2a-\frac c2-\frac d2.\end{align}So, pick $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb C$ such that the RHS of the three equalities from above are equal to $0$, $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}(=e^{\pi i/4})$, and $3i$ respectively. That means that you should take$$a=3i+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}},\ b=\frac d2-(1+2i)\sqrt{2}-6i\text{ and }c=-d+(2+2i)\sqrt{2}+6i.$$The only thing that remains to be done is to pick $d$ such that $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $2$. This only means that $az^3+bz^2+cz+d\ne0$ when $z=2$, which is equivalent to asserting that $d\ne-4\sqrt2-12i$. So, you can simply take $d=0$, in which case$$a=3i+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}},\ b=-(1+2i)\sqrt{2}-6i\text{ and }c=(2+2i)\sqrt{2}+6i.$$

Noting that $\{z \in \mathbb C: z^2-2z+2 =0\} = \{1 \pm i\}$ we let
$$
f_0=\pi,\quad f_1 = \frac{1}{(z-2)^2} + \frac{3i}{z-2}, \quad f_2 = \frac{e^{i\pi/4}(z-(1-i))}{z^2-2z+2}
$$
and set $f= f_0 + f_1+f_2$, then $f_0$ is constant, $f_1$ is holomorphic everywhere except $z=2$, and $f_2$ has a removeable singularity at $z=1-i$ and a simple pole at $z=1+i$ with residue $e^{i\pi/4}$ and thus defines a holomorphic function on $\Omega$. Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ tend to $0$ as $z \to \infty$ it follows that $f(z)\to \pi$ as $z \to \infty$.
Thus $f\colon \Omega\to \mathbb C$ satisfies the four conditions in the OP.
